# PayPal don't make callback to store

Tags: xml, paypal, callback

I have problem with PayPal mechanism InstantUpdate. 
I set up callback url to SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType.
But on paypal site when I change shipping options I haven't any call to callback url.
Example of XML request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cc="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes" xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:ed="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes" xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <ns:RequesterCredentials>
         <ebl:Credentials>
            <ebl:Username>****************</ebl:Username>
            <ebl:Password>****************</ebl:Password>
            <ebl:Signature>****************</ebl:Signature>
         </ebl:Credentials>
      </ns:RequesterCredentials>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:SetExpressCheckoutReq>
         <ns:SetExpressCheckoutRequest>
            <ebl:Version>117.0</ebl:Version>
            <ebl:SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails>
               <ebl:ReturnURL>*****************/confirm?type=EC</ebl:ReturnURL>
               <ebl:CancelURL>*****************/cancel?type=EC</ebl:CancelURL>
               <ebl:MaxAmount currencyID="USD">592.95</ebl:MaxAmount>
               <ebl:NoShipping>2</ebl:NoShipping>
               <ebl:AddressOverride>0</ebl:AddressOverride>
               <ebl:LocaleCode>en_US</ebl:LocaleCode>
               <ebl:Address>
                  <ebl:Name>P M</ebl:Name>
                  <ebl:Street1>Avenue</ebl:Street1>
                  <ebl:Street2>5</ebl:Street2>
                  <ebl:CityName>New York</ebl:CityName>
                  <ebl:StateOrProvince>KS</ebl:StateOrProvince>
                  <ebl:Country>US</ebl:Country>
                  <ebl:PostalCode>10001</ebl:PostalCode>
               </ebl:Address>
               <ebl:SolutionType>Mark</ebl:SolutionType>
               <ebl:ShippingMethod>ShippingMethodStandard</ebl:ShippingMethod>
               <ebl:AllowNote>0</ebl:AllowNote>
               <ebl:CallbackURL>*****************/callback</ebl:CallbackURL>
               <ebl:PaymentDetails>
                  <ebl:OrderTotal currencyID="USD">592.95</ebl:OrderTotal>
                  <ebl:ItemTotal currencyID="USD">574.00</ebl:ItemTotal>
                  <ebl:ShippingTotal currencyID="USD">18.95</ebl:ShippingTotal>
                  <ebl:InvoiceID>o1170001</ebl:InvoiceID>
                  <ebl:ButtonSource>PayPal_SDK</ebl:ButtonSource>
                  <ebl:PaymentDetailsItem>
                     <ebl:Name>item48000001</ebl:Name>
                     <ebl:Number>item48000001</ebl:Number>
                     <ebl:Quantity>2</ebl:Quantity>
                     <ebl:Amount currencyID="USD">280.00</ebl:Amount>
                     <ebl:Description>item48000001</ebl:Description>
                  </ebl:PaymentDetailsItem>
                  <ebl:PaymentDetailsItem>
                     <ebl:Name>item48000002</ebl:Name>
                     <ebl:Number>item48000002</ebl:Number>
                     <ebl:Quantity>1</ebl:Quantity>
                     <ebl:Amount currencyID="USD">14.00</ebl:Amount>
                     <ebl:Description>item48000002</ebl:Description>
                  </ebl:PaymentDetailsItem>
                  <ebl:PaymentAction>Order</ebl:PaymentAction>
                  <ebl:PaymentRequestID>o1170001</ebl:PaymentRequestID>
               </ebl:PaymentDetails>
               <ebl:FlatRateShippingOptions>
                  <ebl:ShippingOptionIsDefault>false</ebl:ShippingOptionIsDefault>
                  <ebl:ShippingOptionAmount currencyID="USD">6.50</ebl:ShippingOptionAmount>
                  <ebl:ShippingOptionName>Ground</ebl:ShippingOptionName>
               </ebl:FlatRateShippingOptions>
               <ebl:FlatRateShippingOptions>
                  <ebl:ShippingOptionIsDefault>false</ebl:ShippingOptionIsDefault>
                  <ebl:ShippingOptionAmount currencyID="USD">9.50</ebl:ShippingOptionAmount>
                  <ebl:ShippingOptionName>Two Day</ebl:ShippingOptionName>
               </ebl:FlatRateShippingOptions>
               <ebl:FlatRateShippingOptions>
                  <ebl:ShippingOptionIsDefault>true</ebl:ShippingOptionIsDefault>
                  <ebl:ShippingOptionAmount currencyID="USD">18.95</ebl:ShippingOptionAmount>
                  <ebl:ShippingOptionName>Next Day</ebl:ShippingOptionName>
               </ebl:FlatRateShippingOptions>
               <ebl:CallbackTimeout>6</ebl:CallbackTimeout>
               <ebl:CallbackVersion>61.0</ebl:CallbackVersion>
            </ebl:SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails>
         </ns:SetExpressCheckoutRequest>
      </ns:SetExpressCheckoutReq>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

May be I forgot set some parameters?

Comment: Do you have the token that you got back from that call?

Comment: Yes, I have. After send information to PayPal, I got token, and after that redirect to PayPal. PayPal redirect me to confirm or cancrl url's.

Comment: What I meant was, could you please provide the token that you received back from the SetExpressCheckout call?  If you could provide that, I could look up that token from my end and try to determine why the callback was not working.

Comment: <Token xsi:type="ebl:ExpressCheckoutTokenType">EC-9TT99902SF316380F</Token>

Comment: From my end, it looks like the hostname of your callback server isn't listed in the public DNS.  Is this server accessible to the outside world?  (Remember that PayPal is going to be the one calling your callback script, not the buyer's browser.)

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will check it.